# How to unit test, if part of the tested functionality is needed by all test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I have a function that parses a textfile and converts the content into some kind of data structure. Besides the very basic success case i also want to test, if certain edge cases are processed correctly (For example skipping lines marked as a comment / Initialize additional data fields if a control token is present in the parsed file).

All of these  edge cases would fail if the general parsing algorithm doesnt work. How do you manage this kind of dependency while testing? I would probably just ignore it and write the test cases, thinking that fixing one of the broken ones would fix the rest, if the general functionality is broken.

Comment: Are you talking about the case where many tests exercise the same piece of code, and there is a bug in this piece ? In this case, many tests will fail, but that's probably fine.

You might want to write several small tests so that it's easy to pinpoint which code is broken ; but if all your suite is red because the "happy path" is broken, that will show up, and you'll just fix it to get green tests back.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what i was talking about. I guess i will just go with that then.